# TS2304 Cannot find name 'Set' in electron-builder

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron-builder

I want to use the AppUpdater in electron-builder in my Electron Application.

When importing the updater in my main.ts file:

```
import { autoUpdater } from "electron-updater"
```

The following error comes up when running the application:

```
node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/httpExecutor.d.ts(54,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/builder-util-runtime/out/rfc2253Parser.d.ts(1,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

After research it seems I have to show the Typescript transpiler how to deal with these particular typings but trying different combinations of targets/libraries in my ts.config file, nothing seems to help.

How can I make this typescript definition file work?

Here is my config file:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
        "environments": [
            "./environments"
        ]
    },
    "types": [
        "node",
        "jasmine"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please Let me  know the version of electron-builder

Answer (score 2):

Try running 
`npm install --save-dev @types/es6-collections`

You can find more context of the solution here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16587